# angularjs select options not getting populated from model

Tags: angularjs

On my home page I have a select list but I can't figure out why it's not getting populated with data from the model.  The select list is supposed to hold product categories.

Here's my HTML:

```
<select 
    ng-options="c.name for c in search.productCategories track by c.id" 
    ng-model="search.selectedProductCategory">
</select>
```

I have a base controller on the body of my html:

```
<body ng-controller="baseCtrl">
```

I'm using `$routeProvider` like so:

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "app/views/home.html",
        controller: "home",
        resolve: {
            productCategories: productCategoriesResolver
        }
    })
...
...
```

My controller looks looks this:

```
function home($scope, productCategories) {
    ...
    ...
    $scope.search.productCategories = productCategories;
}
```

The resolver function is:

```
function productCategoriesResolver(productCategoryService) {
    return productCategoryService.getProductCategories().then(function(categories) {
        return categories;
    });
}
```

I've checked and `$scope.search.productCategories` is populated with something similar to this.

```
[{id: 1, name: 'Cat-A'}, {id: 2, name: 'Cat-B'}, ...]
```

I thought maybe it was something to do with the nested controller but I've reproduced a working nested controller [solution](https://codepen.io/poakey1/pen/KXNvwp) .

I've tried wrapping in an `$apply` but there's already a digest cycle in progress , tried a `$timeout` too but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your ng-options. Try like this:

```
<select 
    ng-options="c as c.name for c in search.productCategories track by c.id" 
    ng-model="search.selectedProductCategory">
</select>
```

Comment: Same problem... and it works with the original syntax in the codepen link I provided in the question.

Comment: Here is plunker with routerprovider: https://plnkr.co/edit/lXlZfhHYKfduWHew861O?p=preview where select is showing. Don't know what causing that beahavior in your case.

Comment: No errors - but I think I know what it is - I have an old js reference to bootstrap-select.js which is conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

I had an old reference to `bootstrap-select.js` which was conflicting and causing problems.